# Type conversion of STL structure in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Context: I create the

> ```
> std::map<type, Base>
> ```

inside a function where the map is given as reference parameter. This function is ideally called from somewhere with the reference parameter

> ```
> std::map<type, Derived>&.
> ```

What is the best way to convert from

```
std::map<type, Derived>
```

to

```
std::map<type, Basis>
```

where `Basis` is the Basis class of `Derived`? I have already unsuccessfully tried to convert through a direct cast. I would prefer not to switch from Derived to Derived* and from Base to Base*.

I would need to run the function to create the map with the Basis elements and then get it back and work with the map with Derived elements.

Comment: Please add some addition detail that what container you have and what container you want to go to.  Also what you have tried.

Comment: If you talk about "where Basis is..." then something from before should have that word in it. You are essentially asking a question like "I have a problem where stuff does not work" without any further details.

Comment: Are you going to want to do something like `basis_map[something].some_function();` and have the function of the derived class called?

Comment: maybe instead of switching to `Base*` you would prefer switching to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`?

Comment: Specify your problem with using pointers (that is, proper pointers, not raw pointers). If you go without pointers, other than like in the answer of John Zwinck, the only thing that would be feasible is doing it manually with some converting method that makes sure that no slicing happens.

Comment: Finally I chose to implement a constructor Derived(Basis). I worked only with std::map(type, Basis) and only in some places I used the constructor mentioned above to get the other map. It is not a general solution but the particular structure of my problem favours this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cannot convert from a container of Derived to a container of Base.  For one thing, if Derived is larger than Base, what would happen to the extra bits?

If you want something approaching a solution without raw pointers, use this:

```
std::map<type, std::unique_ptr<Base>>
```

Then you can put either Base or Derived objects into the map.